# iPhone/iPod touch/iPad IDE/text editor

Tags: ios, ide

I know that there are a multitude of text editors for the iPhone. I'm looking for a good text editor, preferably on that, which has syntax highlighting and also is good for application development on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this the other week...

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/for-i/id363493710?mt=8

I don't have a i..Pod/Phone/Pad so can't tell you whether it is good or not. But it has a good rating and at least syntax highlighting for c++